# transfer file from AWS s3 budget to ec2 instance using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I have been working on a project where we will have a website process on EC2 server. In my project, I was able to write a php code that allow users to upload file from web server to AWS S3 budget. However, in order to access that file from EC2, i think we need to transfer file from S3 budget to EC2 instance. I saw that there is a unix command line way to do that, but the project i'm working on is based on PHP/HTML/JSON. I wonder is there a way or tutorial to access or transfer file from S3 to EC2 instance using PHP?
Thanks

Comment: what does "s3 budget" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to transfer the file from S3 to EC2, in fact, this would be a waste of resources. Instead, you can generate a signed url pointing to the file directly on S3 (even if the bucket/file is private). This link can also be set to expire after a certain period. Here's an example using the AWS PHP SDK:

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php'; //SDK autoloader file

//*** Initiate an S3 client
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "public_key",
    'secret' => "private_key",
    'region' => "your s3 region"
));

$url = $client->getObjectUrl("bucket_name", "full_object_name", "+1 minutes"[optional]);

echo $url; //Print the direct S3 link to the file, which will expire in 1 minute.
           //This will work even if the bucket is private.
```

**[update]**
If you still need to download the file from S3 to EC2, do this:

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php'; //SDK autoloader file

//*** Initiate an S3 client
$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "public_key",
    'secret' => "private_key",
    'region' => "your s3 region"
));

$result = $client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket'  => "bucket_name",
    'Key'     => "name of file",
    'SaveAs'  => "ec2 path to save the file at"
));

echo $result; //make sure download worked.
```

Further reading:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

Comment: i need to able to able to get the file from s3 because the code for my ec2 need the file the client upload to display it. It's not the clients who need the file but me.

Comment: The amazon documentation has all the answers you need, I suggest you review it. Still though, see my updated answer.